# Platform independent Webform CiviCRM

Tags: webform-civicrm, joomla

Is there any work being done on a platform independent Webform CiviCRM or equivalent? Our site is heavily invested in Joomla but we just can't seem to get CiviCRM to fit our needs without the customizability of Webform CiviCRM. I'm wondering if I will need to do a rebuild and migration to Drupal just for this plug-in or if there is hope in waiting, or places I can try to help.

Answer (score 2):

There are some developments on generic ways of passing data between forms and CMS but they are at very early baby stages.

However they focus on the situation where CiviCRM is on a different server then the public website as this is the most secure configuration that best allows following European privacy guidelines. So that would certainly not help you right now.

Having said so, have you thought about separating CiviCRM and your public facing website because of security reasons?

Comment: I hadn't considered that before... seems like there could be some benefits, but it also seems like a pain to try to build a new Drupal site that matches my Joomla one, and then direct our users there for every donation, membership registration, or class registration. And then to not have the capability to include class lists, events, or fundraising campaigns on my main site.

We are planning a site redisgn in the fall, and this is tempting me to go Drupal even though we've already begun work on a new Joomla theme.

Comment: Agree it is a pain, but it does require a decision IMO :-)

Comment: There are significant advantages of using Drupal. One route we have done for a few clients who are already invested in eg WP or J, but need the bells and whistles that Drupal adds, is to skin up Drupal site to look the same, so it makes it fairly invisible when a user skips from one to the other, but agree that blocks of eg 'upcoming events' then requires iframe solutions if you want them on the non-CRM site

Comment: I think I'll test this out. I'm curious if all of the appropriate information will pass through if I use a Joomla wrapper. Could be a nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Presently there is no platform independent Webform tool for CiviCRM, no.

One other option to use CiviCRM on a separate site, perhaps as a subdomain. Then you would have the issues of matching the look.

The other option is to use an iFrame on your current site which draws in a virtually un-styled Drupal "sub-site" which is just used for CiviCRM. This at least keeps the user on your main site and avoids the problem of matching your site's look.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to use Angular Forms to do something similar?

My first thought would be Symfony forms to do this, but the dependencies are high.  There would have to be a Doctrine model for all the CiviCRM entities, and while there's a Symfony function for generating these it's only about 75% effective.  It would take a lot of work to complete the other 25% and test the whole 100%.  Thus, the thought that Angular Forms - already in Civi - might be an easier way.